# Back-to-back Schengen visa applications

Tags: schengen

I am about to finish a trip to the Schengen are (a single country) and intend to travel again to other Schengen countries in August. Is it safe to apply for another Schengen visa immediately after the completion of the first visit?

Comment: Why do you assume it is a problem ?

Comment: I am a bit skeptical that Visa Officers may think that why i wanna do back to back visits in Schengen Zone, and why i didn't did it in one go. Actually, i should have done it in One Go but i didn't planned it well.